# UTF-8 string encoding in .NET for shipping with Restsharp

Tags: .net, utf-8, restsharp

I have developed a program that generates a digitally signed XML file, encoded in UTF8, which I send to an API.
The problem is that when certain characters are included, such as "or", the API rejects the submission because it is badly encoded.
On the left you can see the content of the file and on the right what the API receives.

[image: First picture of code]

The file that is generated according to the Notepad++ editor and some online tool is UTF8 encoded. If I open it in hexadecimal I see that the encoding of ó is c3b3 which is the correct one in UTF-8.

[image: Second picture of output]

The program is developed in VB.Net with .NET Framework 4.8. For sending to the API I use Restsharp (106.12.0.0). The program reads the file in a string and sends it to API

```
Dim sr As New StreamReader(arcXMLfirmado)
cadXML = sr.ReadToEnd
sr.Close()
sr = Nothing

request = New RestRequest(Method.POST)
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml")
request.AddHeader("charset", "UTF-8")
request.AddParameter("text/xml", cadXML, ParameterType.RequestBody)

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

cliente = New RestClient(URLapi)
cliente.ClientCertificates = New X509Certificate2Collection
cliente.ClientCertificates.Add(oCertificado)
tsEnvio = Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
cliente.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
response = cliente.Execute(request)
```

How do I encode the read string in UTF-8 for sending ?

Comment: The following may help - you may need to specify the encoding when using StreamReader: https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2019/01/23/correctly-reading-encoded-text-with-the-streamreader-in-net/   -- try changing the StreamReader constructor to something like:  Dim sr As New StreamReader(arcXMLfirmado, Encoding.UTF8);